# Find the time interval with the most rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, bigdata

I have the following DataFrame in which each row represents a bike rental:

(Duration is in seconds)

[image: DataFrame bike rentals]

I'm very new to pandas and Big Data. I'm trying to find the **specific time* in which the most amount of bikes are currently being used and what that maximum value is**.

*Time being Date with hour and minute precision.* *

The duration of the rentals vary from 60 seconds to 17270400 seconds (199 days)

The dataframe has a total of rows of 67.000.

I know the solution might be pretty trivial but I've been thinking and searching for a while and I'm stuck with this.

Here's some of the data of the .csv (selected some records from the top, middle and end of the file for a little bit of diversity in the data)

http://pastebin.com/Tgnupe7K

EDIT: Added pastebin with some of the raw data from the .csv

Comment: This is a good question.  However, you done a few things that won't help you get a good answer.  Read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get a better idea on how to ask a quesiton.  In short, make it easy for those of us who answer questions by posting data we can copy and paste.  Images of data is frowned upon because it's annoying to recreate your data from the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to consider the times when each bike enters and exits use, denoting entering use as +1 and exiting use as -1.  Take these times, sort them, then take a cumulative sum over the +1/-1's.  The maximum value of the cumulative sum will give the maximum number of bikes out at a given time.

I'll use some data I mocked up for my example:

```
# Setup some fake data.
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
n = 67
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start_date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=10), size=n),
    'duration': np.random.randint(1, 10**5, size=n)
})
df['start_date'] += pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(1000, size=n), unit='m')
```

Then the procedure is as follows:

```
# Combine the entrance and exit times with the appropriate sign.
bike_times = pd.concat([
    pd.Series(1, index=df['start_date']),
    pd.Series(-1, index=df['start_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'], unit='s')),
])

# Sort the dates and take the cumulative sum of the signs.
bike_times = bike_times.sort_index().cumsum()

# Find the max time and number of bikes.
max_dt = bike_times.idxmax()
max_bikes = bike_times.max()
```

In the code above, `max_dt` will yield the starting time at which the bikes are at a maximum.  To find the end time, just look at the next index value in `bike_times`.